# Generic exception using Spring JpaRepository implementation

Tags: java, spring, generics, exception, spring-data-jpa

i am using Spring data, specifically SimpleJpaRepository (JpaRepository  implemenetation) and i cannot make it work using it as a bean

```
@Bean
protected <domainClass, L> SimpleJpaRepository<domainClass, Long> getSimpleJpaRepository(Class domainClass) {
    return new SimpleJpaRepository<>(domainClass, this.entityManager);
}
```

And it compiles but i have this error at runtime

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:94)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:200)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:259)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:261)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:219)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientDAO' defined in com.queens.movies.persistence.config.DAOConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.queens.movies.persistence.dao.client.ClientDAO]: Factory method 'clientDAO' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30 cannot be cast to org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:68)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:86)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.queens.movies.persistence.dao.client.ClientDAO]: Factory method 'clientDAO' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30 cannot be cast to org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30 cannot be cast to org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository
    at com.queens.movies.persistence.config.DAOConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b5678f6d.getSimpleJpaRepository(<generated>)
    at com.queens.movies.persistence.config.DAOConfiguration.clientDAO(DAOConfiguration.java:35)
    at com.queens.movies.persistence.config.DAOConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b5678f6d.CGLIB$clientDAO$0(<generated>)
    at com.despegar.movies.persistence.config.DAOConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b5678f6d$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$471e7923.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
    at com.despegar.movies.persistence.config.DAOConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b5678f6d.clientDAO(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 43 more
```

But if i write this it works:

```
private SimpleJpaRepository<Client, Long> support = new SimpleJpaRepository<>(Client.class, this.entityManager);
```

Do you know what is going on ?

---

### EDIT

This is how i am invoking that method by  another bean:

```
@Bean
public ClientDAO clientDAO(){
     SimpleJpaRepository<Client, Long> support = this.getSimpleJpaRepository(Client.class);
     return new ClientDAOImpl(support);
}
```

Comment: How do you pass the `domainClass` to your currently failing code?

Comment: It suppouse to be generic, in this case, for example i would be  passing it a Client.class which i created and is an @Entity class ()

Comment: I meant I want to see the exact line of code you are using to invoke it.

Comment: i have another bean which needs this object to be injected in it. im editting the post with the invoking part

Comment: May I ask what you are trying to achieve? An important idea behind Spring Data is that you don't instantiate the repositories but just specify interfaces and Spring Data creates an implementation based on that. So as long as you don't try to do something fancy, this looks somewhat wrong.